# Replace apply function with lapply

Tags: r, apply, lapply, mclapply

I am creating a data set to compute the aggregate values for different combinations of words using regex. Each row has a unique regex value which I want to check against another dataset and find the number of times it appeared in it.

The first dataset (df1) looks like this :

```
   word1    word2               pattern
   air      10     (^|\\s)air(\\s.*)?\\s10($|\\s)
 airport    20   (^|\\s)airport(\\s.*)?\\s20($|\\s)
   car      30     (^|\\s)car(\\s.*)?\\s30($|\\s)
```

The other dataset (df2) from which I want to match this looks like

```
   sl_no    query
   1      air 10     
   2    airport 20   
   3    airport 20
   3    airport 20
   3      car 30
```

The final output I want should look like
       word1    word2   total_occ
       air      10        1
     airport    20        3
       car      30        1

I am able to do this by using apply in R

```
process <- 
function(x) 
{
  length(grep(x[["pattern"]], df2$query))
}           

df1$total_occ=apply(df1,1,process)
```

but find it time taking since my dataset is pretty big.

I found out that "mclapply" function of "parallel" package can be used to run such things on multicores, for which I am trying to run lapply first. Its giving me error saying

```
lapply(df,process)
```

> Error in x[, "pattern"] : incorrect number of dimensions

Please let me know what changes should I make to run lapply correctly.

Comment: You're iterating over the patterns, so that should be your first arg to `lapply`, right?

Comment: Here;s why you get that error: `lapply` will apply some function to each element of a list in turn; so the function has to be able to operate on the elements of the list.  The elements in this context of a dataframe are its columns, so you are asking R to apply `process` to each column of `df`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just `lapply()` over the `pattern`?

Here I've just pulled out your `pattern` but this could just as easily be `df$pattern`

```
pattern <- c("(^|\\s)air(\\s.*)?\\s10($|\\s)",
             "(^|\\s)airport(\\s.*)?\\s20($|\\s)",
             "(^|\\s)car(\\s.*)?\\s30($|\\s)")
```

Using your data for `df2`

```
txt <- "sl_no    query
   1      'air 10'     
   2    'airport 20'   
   3    'airport 20'
   3    'airport 20'
   3      'car 30'"
df2 <- read.table(text = txt, header = TRUE)
```

Just iterate on `pattern` directly

```
> lapply(pattern, grep, x = df2$query)
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 2 3 4

[[3]]
[1] 5
```

If you want more compact output as suggested in your question, you'll need to run `lengths()` over the output returned (Thanks to **@Frank** for pointing out the new function `lengths()`.)). Eg

```
lengths(lapply(pattern, grep, x = df2$query))
```

which gives

```
> lengths(lapply(pattern, grep, x = df2$query))
[1] 1 3 1
```

You can add this to the original data via

```
dfnew <- cbind(df1[, 1:2],
               Count = lengths(lapply(pattern, grep, x = df2$query)))
```

Comment: And then `lengths` on that if they have the latest version of R

Comment: @Frank Yup; I just noticed that part of the Q as it wasn't in any markup. Added that now.

Comment: Hm, I see you've added a version with `length`, but you can keep your original way and just wrap it in the new function `lengths`, like `lengths(lapply(...etc...))`

Comment: @Frank +1 I didn't know about `lengths()`! Thanks for the heads-up on that new function. Will update the answer. (When did `lengths()` get into R?)

Comment: Just in 3.2.0. I saw someone show that it's a lot faster than `sapply(x,length)`, but mostly it's just really convenient.

Comment: Yep, convenient indeed. Need to decide whether to start using that in some of my packages. Would clean up some code but at expense of dependency on R 3.2.0...

Comment: @Gavin - Thank you for the detailed solution, this is exactly what I wanted to do. This just saved me a whole lot of digging :)